# How to remove "quick view / quick preview" area from finder window?

Tags: macos, finder

How can i remove / hide the "quick view / quick preview" area from finder (see markup attached) ?

Im running Big Sur, but I think Ive seen this area in previous versions of MacOS / OSX also.

[image: screenshot of finder showing the quick view area]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Shift+Cmd+P` shortcut for that. It's in the View drop-down menu as well, as "Show preview" or something like that (I use macOS in PT-BR, so not sure about EN-US).

Comment: Thanks - in the EN_US menu the wording is "show preview" / "hide preview"